# "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL"

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

почему-то не получается добавить данные в базу, пишет "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам синтаксис запроса:

```
SELECT abonent.ID, abonent.[FIO abonenta], abonent.tarif, abonent.uslugi, abonent.balans, abonent.[data plateja], abonent.status

FROM abonent;

INSERT INTO abonent (ID, [FIO abonenta], tarif, uslugi, balans, [data plateja], status) VALUES ('6', 'Кузьмин Е.О.', 'Стандарт', 'тв+телефония', '-11', '25.08.2016', 'выкл')
```

Comment: MS Access не допускает мультизапросов.

Comment: Вставил только одну строку
INSERT INTO abonent (ID) VALUES ('6')
Но ошибка та же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так, как в документации: запрос на добавление нескольких записей

```
    INSERT INTO target [( field1 [, field2 
    [, …]])] [IN externaldatabase ] SELECT 
    [ source .] field1 [, field2 [, …] FROM 
    табличное выражение
```